# Add custom autocomplete snippets to Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Is there a way to do this?

e.g. make typing 'np' bring up 'import numpy as np' as a suggestion.

I've tried looking around to no avail.

Comment: You should probably look around for some python import snippets for atom.

Comment: @coderman1234 found it :) https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

Answer (score 1):

damn this works even better.
https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

and for that import numpy example:

```
'.source.python':
  'import numpy as np':
    'prefix': 'np'
    'body': 'import numpy as np'
```